# Update multiple rows with the value from the selected column

Tags: mysql, rows

I am new to SQL, I have a requirement where I have to increment the value in a specific column by 1 and update that value in the same column based on the id.

Here is what I want,

```
    UPDATE books SET version_num = 
  (SELECT (version_num + 1) FROM books WHERE book_recid IN 
('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', '73255df2-413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405'))
WHERE book_recid IN 
('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', '73255df2-413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405');
```

I know the above query won't work. I want a query to update the values in the database like above.

Comment: Do you want to update the `version_num` in both the `books` and `tag_config_params` tables?

Comment: Sorry, modifying the query, 

UPDATE books SET version_num = 
  (SELECT (version_num + 1) FROM books WHERE book_recid IN 
('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', '73255df2-413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405'))
WHERE book_recid IN 
('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', '73255df2-413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405');

This is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple to add 1 to a column.

You have just over complicated your query.

```
UPDATE books SET version_num = version_num +1
WHERE book_recid IN ('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', 
                     '73255df2-413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a from in the update query

```
UPDATE A SET col1 = something
FROM B
INNER JOIN C on B.col4 = C.col5
WHERE A.col2 = B.col3
```

In your case, it could be something like the following

```
UPDATE books b SET version_num = tcp.version_num + 1
FROM tag_config_params tcp
WHERE tcp.book_recid = b.book_recid
AND tcp.book_recid IN ('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', '73255df2-413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405');
```

I'm assuming that book_recid is a foreign key relationship here.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
UPDATE books
    SET version_num = tb1.vers
from (
    SELECT (version_num + 1) as vers FROM tag_config_params
     WHERE book_recid IN
  ('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', '73255df2-  413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405')
) tb1
WHERE book_recid IN 
('72b72282-707b-4dd4-ab08-f5a085e92a2b', '73255df2-413e-4aad-892d-edc08ffa3405');
```